# How to detect WebP from a raw datastream - what are the start bits?

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm able to detect the image type from a raw data stream, using the start bits from these file formats:

```
$formats['jpg'] = "\xFF\xD8\xFF";
$formats['gif'] = "GIF";
$formats['png'] = "\x89\x50\x4e\x47\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a";
$formats['bmp'] = "BM";
$formats['psd'] = "8BPS";
$formats['swf'] = "FWS";
```

But I haven't found the start bits from the webp format. Can someone tell me, or let me know how to find out?

Comment: on https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TOwkELYuKB8J:https://oroboro.com/image-format-magic-bytes/+&cd=11&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr found this "WebP
WebP files are technically RIFF files. RIFF is a container format like TIFF. WebP files are RIFF files that contain a single WEBP chunk.To detect it, first check that the first 4 bytes are “RIFF”, and then that bytes 8-11 are “WEBP”."